AWS IAM policy for partial username match (extract username from SSO)
We are using single sign-on for AWS users, so when a user logs in they assume a role, and they don't have an actual IAM user account.
We use CodeCommit, which requires an SSH key added to an IAM user.
This means we create user accounts for developers so there is some way to upload an SSH key, but we don't want developers logging in to the AWS Console with that account because it bypasses our SSO system.
This means developers can't upload their own SSH keys, because they log in as an SSO user which is different to their SSH IAM user, so they have no permission to upload SSH keys.
I would like to write an IAM policy that permits this access, as the usernames between the two systems are the same.
Currently trying to upload an SSH key gives an error like this:

User: arn:sts::12345:assumed-role/Developers/usernameA is not authorized to perform: iam:UploadSSHPublicKey on resource: user usernameA because no identity-based policy allows the iam:UploadSSHPublicKey action

The error is because the logged in "username" is assumed-role/Developers/usernameA but the IAM account name is usernameA and as they are different, access is denied.
I need a policy that somehow trims the username off the end of the signed-in username, only if it starts with assumed-role, and compares that to the IAM account name.
The AWS-managed policy is a good starting point, I am just unsure what conditions to add to it in order to get the desired behaviour:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}


I tend to create an IAM user, give permissions only for CodeCommit, and generate CodeCommit credentials. That user can only access CodeCommit, nothing else. I suspect you there's a way to give SSO users access to CodeCommit, but that's a vague memory from a while ago and could be incorrect.

@Tim That's what we've done.  But since you can't easily give SSO users access to CodeCommit (without requiring everyone to install helper scripts) I'm hoping there's a way to grant the SSO users access to upload SSH creds to those matching IAM users.

Oh yeah, I remember now. Helper scripts isn't a nice way to do things. I give each user an IAM account with the AWSCodeCommitFullAccess managed policy and use git https credentials. That way there's no need to let them download / upload ssh keys.
